# Altium : Bill of materials organization

Tags: altium, bom

Is there a way to get one component per line in the bill of material ?
For example, currently I have two different designator who have same value and they share the same line. I would like to get one designator per line.

Anybody know how to make this ?

Currently I have my bill of material as below and as you can see this is a bit mess up. I don't know why Altium is displaying this way ? Why it doesn't separate them ?
[image]

Comment: I generally group by description and comment, or by description and a custom parameter I use called "Notes" which include comments like "DNP" for "Do Not Populate".

Answer (score 3):

They are grouped by Comment and Footprint.

It really looks like you just edited the description on one 0.47 μF to be 0.1 μF (or comment the other way), rather than also changing the description and value tags. I find it's a better way of working to actually replace one with another, as this avoids this kind of hassle.

You can change the grouping (by comment or value in stead of description) and that makes more sense in several occasions, or even turn off all the grouping. In case your Fab needs an itemised list with location and rotation for each component, for example. But it seems you have a whole different issue, that may keep popping up in unpredictable ways, until you actually fix the offending component, rather than fixing one symptom at a time.

Comment: I guess I didn't quite understand the depth of OP's problems, but yeah, it really pays to populate your data properly. @chris, you may need to go back and create a parts database, or spend a bunch of time hand-adjusting your projects to sort out your data.

Comment: What do you guys usually input in Comment and in Description ?

Comment: @chris Nothing but the right information for all specifics of the part. Comment a short value or distinguishing mark, such as part number, description more words to fully specify anything important when making quick choices.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all of the Grouped Columns. You can do this by right-clicking and ungrouping them. This sends the un-selected column back to the All Columns list.

Are you sure you don't want each line item to represent a single part number though? That is a more typical way to organize a BOM.

Comment: Yes you are right.